# Can I deduce the info such as the bitsize of an LFSR from multiple ciphertext messages?

Tags: cryptanalysis, lfsr

If I encrypt the same message multiple times (>10000 times) with the same LFSR can I then somehow retrieve some information on the LFSR? I'm looking for information like bit size, polynomial used. The ciphertext is different for each encrypted message.

The assumption is that cipher is 48bytes in size. The message is most likely encrypted with a 32 byte long key (stream) generated by the LFSR. Each byte of the message XOR-ed along the the way.

How could one approach this challenge?

edit:
The LFSR used is a Galois primitive. That's additional known intel.

Comment: I hope that some general techniques can be written in answers below. But if this is a *cryptographically strong LFSR-based* stream cipher then the output should be indistinguishable from random and it should therefore be impossible to extract information. There are however quite a few weak and/or broken LFSR based stream ciphers out there.

Comment: So without at least knowing some plaintext-ciphertext that cant be resolved ?

Comment: Worse. You may not even know it if you have plaintext / ciphertext pairs as the key stream is indistinguishable from random. That is called IND_CPA security, and as an IV is clearly involved in the system the scheme may be IND_CPA (chosen plaintext) secure.

Comment: Hmm, I cant have my own message encrypted by the other party. I could do it myself but that would be based on quite a lot of assumptions and I dont even know the bitsize of the LFSR. It seems to be pretty big as I can download the same encrypted message/file > 40k times and all are unique. I thought I could check if the cipher repeats at some point but so far no luck.

Comment: And that's called a *cycle*, which is entered if the *internal state* repeats. But **if** the internal state is 48 bytes (384 bits) you can wait until kingdom come before that happens. (Kingdom come, sheesh I'm getting religious as well :P)

Comment: Well, that would be a desaster for this challenge. But as it **is** a solvable challenge there must be some way and I seem to still miss something. Thanks for your responses though. Best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77572/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-zapho-oxx).